# Playing/Pausing iTunes while another app plays media

Tags: itunes, mac, music, youtube

While browsing on Safari and listening to iTunes I come across a video and then press the "play" button on the keyboard (to stop the music while I watch the video) it starts/stops the video instead of the music (I have no control over the music).

How can I quickly play/pause my music without affecting the video?

Comment: As I have just found and reported [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/354234/282581) if the other app is VLC, then now it can automatically pause iTunes and Spotify when playing media, and it can even resume them afterwards! I don't use this option, but from your question I thought you may like it (VLC can also play Youtube videos and playlists). Refer to the linked post for the details about how to enable the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> (switch to iTunes)
2. <kbd>space</kbd> (pause or play music)
3. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> (switch back to App)

---

[Mac Media Key Forwarder](https://github.com/milgra/macmediakeyforwarder) allows you to set the media keys to only control either Spotify or iTunes (instead of whichever app you happen to be using).

Answer (score 4):

If you're not averse to downloading some of the most useful software I've ever installed you can set the play/pause button (on my keyboard <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>) to *always* control iTunes using [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements).

Just add something like the following rule to `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json`

```
{  
   "description": "Play/pause button should only control iTunes.",
   "manipulators": [  
      {  
         "from": {  
            "key_code": "f8",
            "modifiers": {  
               "mandatory": [  
                  "fn"
               ]
            }
         },
         "to": [  
            {  
               "shell_command": "osascript -e 'tell application \"iTunes\" to playpause'"
            }
         ],
         "type": "basic"
      }
   ]
}
```

You may remove the `"modifiers"` part if you normally press <kbd>F8</kbd> *without* pressing <kbd>fn</kbd> to play/pause iTunes.

Then in Karabiner-Elements you'd add your new rule as a complex modification:

[image]

Comment: Getting rid of the modifiers part would look like `"from": {  
            "key_code": "f8"
         },`

Answer (score 2):

Base on the @minseong 's answer, I wrote karabiner complex modification rule.

You can find "Media key only control iTunes" group in the
https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/

Just import and enable it. (Below capture only shows f8 rules, but soon f7 and f9 rules will be added.)

[image: karabiner complex modification rule repository capture]

For more detailed solution, check this link

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250590543

Comment: Needs the obvious update due to the release of `Music.app` in place of `iTunes.app`; I got it to work by doing the following: just go to `~/.config/karabiner/assets`, find the most recently modified `json` after importing the above, make the above name change, and reload the modification in the Karabiner UI.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the iTunes or (since High Sierra) Now Playing widgets to notifications centre:

[image]

On a MacBook at least this becomes even easier because the notification centre is just a two-finger swipe away.

In fact, there's even a keyboard shortcut you can set to open up the notifications centre:

[image]

Comment: nice suggestion! do you find this to be easier than app switcher + key board shortcut?

Comment: I don't really use iTunes that much to be completely honest. If I was having the same problem as you I'd fix it with Karabiner-Elements, which has become my go-to for these kinds of problems. But yes, this is clearly easier than app switcher + keyboard, because <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> won't always go straight to iTunes and you can keep "focus" on whatever app you're currently using instead of having to switch back and forth between different apps.

Comment: I'm used to navigating my apps using cmd-tab so  and prefer to keep my hands on the keyboard when possible (vs. mouse). I still think this will take more time as I would have to mouse over to the pause button, right? Couldn't find another way to pause. Also I typically keep the Notification Center open to notifications vs. "today"