# iTunes automatically pauses when VLC plays a file

Tags: itunes, video, music, vlc, mediaplayer

I noticed that if I have some background music on iTunes and I start playing a VLC video, iTunes automatically stops the music.

Although this can be a very useful thing, I would prefer to have control of it, for example in my case I would like to keep listening the background music when I watch a non-music video.

Is there an option in iTunes to disable pausing? I tried to look at the iTunes options but I didn't find any, perhaps it is a setting which cannot be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long search, I realized the setting to pause iTunes when VLC starts is not in iTunes. It's in VLC.

To disable this, open the VLC preferences and click the "Show All" button in the lower left:

[image: The main VLC Preferences window with an arrow drawn to the Show All button]

Then drill down to `Interface` -> `Main interfaces` -> `macosx` selection and find the `Control external music players` field where you can change it to `Do nothing`, `Pause iTunes and Spotify`, or `Pause and resume iTunes and Spotify`. I selected the first option :-)

[image: Arrows pointing to the location macosx interface location in the VLC preferences panel]

I share this knowledge here in Q&A style in case someone else was struggling with this.